# Help in Salesforce Site Custom URL setup

Tags: force.com-sites, site.com

We are in the middle of launching a new VF Page site in our Salesforce instance.

Site is working if we use the default Salesforce generated site url. (xx.cs.force.com).

Now we are planning to use our custom company domain. So our IT team has confirmed that they have the custom domain available and activated.

example: https://. (https://test.company.ca)

**Below is what we have done:**
1. Created a "CA Certificate" with the Unqiue name as "test.company.ca"
(Just waiting for the Cert to be signed)

2.Setup the domain (test.company.ca) in Salesforce 
Selected the below option
(Salesforce serves the domain over HTTPS, on Salesforce's servers, using your HTTPS certificate
Certificate and Key Lookup (New Window))
Once the cert is signed will select this option with the signed certificate

3. Then we created the new Custom URL and select the above Domain and the Site
4. Then in the Site, we have added the above new custom url

**Question:**
1. Just wondering in the above process, should we ask for any redirection to be setup by the IT team for new custom domain (test.company.ca)

2. Once we have the signed certs, when we open custom domain, if we launch the custom domain https://test.company.ca, will the Site start working.

Can anyone please clarify, if anything else need to be done by our IT team besides activating the domain (test.company.ca)